# socket.io with express to update variables in the DOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

this is the test case...

app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    //other variables

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);


var io = require("socket.io").listen(server)
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
});
```

html_index.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var socket = io.connect();
        socket.on('news', function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
});
```

i get this error

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:26000/socket.io/1/websocket/%3Ch2%3Efile%20not%20found!%20error%20404!%3C/h2%3E' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established. socket.io.js:2438
WS.close socket.io.js:2438
Socket.onDisconnect socket.io.js:1967
Transport.onDisconnect socket.io.js:1362
Transport.onClose socket.io.js:1456
(anonymous function)
```

im using

```
express 3
socket.io 0.9
nodejs 0.10
```

Comment: Works for me.. Where do you see these errors? And what is with port 26000? Isn't the default express port 3000?

Comment: im using 26000, didn't work for me and i cant find the problem, I see this error in the client, using chrome

Comment: The socket is trying to request (un-encoded) `/socket.io/1/websocket/<h2>file not found! error 404!</h2>`. Check `npm ls` for any missing dependencies. Or try deleting and re-installing `socket.io`. Note: `socket.io`'s dependencies includes a [native addon](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), [`ws`](https://npmjs.org/package/ws), which requires [`node-gyp`](https://npmjs.org/package/node-gyp) and [its external dependencies](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation) to install.

Comment: 26000 also works for me on chrome. I really want to help but I can't propagate the error.

Comment: all dependences were checked, i found this... when i change io port to 26001 on server and io.connect('http://localhost:26001'); on client it works

Comment: thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was the port

this is the solution

```
var server = app.listen(26000, function(){ //instead of var server = http.createServer(app);
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.get('port'),
    app.settings.env);
});
//SOCKET.IO
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server)
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
});
```